# How to access APEX application from other Computer?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I just want to my APEX along with Database installed in PC-1, and then rest of PC's just access this application via LAN cable or WiFi.
Still i don't know ORDS installation as well as tomcat.
Help me by providing links.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've already installed APEX in your XE database, the easiest way would be to enable the embedded PL/SQL gateway, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/epg.htm#HTMIG29203 for details.

Using the embedded PL/SQL gateway would be sufficient for sharing APEX over a local network, but I would recommend going down the ORDS + Tomcat path for anything else.